# I am prompted for an Alias Password for signing when the keystore command does not require it

Tags: android, visual-studio, google-play

I am done programming my android app using the Xamarin Android framework. Now I need to publish my app and for me to be able to do that my app needs to pass an internal test laid by Google. So I went to Visual Studio 2022 and changed the mode from **Debug** to **Release** and then I hit the run button which is normally on green. After the build was successful then I went back to the **Release folder** and found two application bundles. One that is signed and another one that is not. When I upload the signed bundle to Play Console then Play Console shows an error that

> You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that was signed in debug mode, you need to sign your APK or Android bundle in release mode

Then when I tried uploading the other one in the same Release folder which is not signed then I get the following error

> The bundle is not signed

**Update**

I did some digging and learnt that I need to sign this bundle with a keystore file.
So I opened the bin folder of the jre and started a command line session there. The command I entered did not prompt me for an alias password but only a keystore password and an alias name. How do I generate a keystore file with the alias and the alias password?

The visual studio sign window requires the following fields to be filled, three of which I have but the other two I have no idea.

**1. Path to the keystore file**

**2. Keystore password**

**3. Alias Name**

**4. Alias Password**

**5. Apk signer additional requirements**

The command I used has the first three, where do I get the other two or how do I key in a new command that will provide at least the first four credentials?

Comment: Have you checked out the official android doc about keystore and singing a bundle? Checkout here: [Sign your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key)

Comment: @AdilSoomro, the alias password is a requirement when I wasn't asked to enter it into the terminal

Answer (score 1):

I generated a key using Android Studio which provides a friendly user interface to enter all the required credentials. I had to manually uninstall the previous version that was not signed and build in release mode to get a signed bundle. Visual Studio and Android Studio use a different file extension for the key store file but if you fill in the right information then it should work